# Role of IView in rendering a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the role of the `IView` when the view engine tries to translate requests for views into `ViewEngineResult` objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging in, this is what I figured is happening. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

When a `ViewResult` is being processed, the action invoker would retrieve the set of installed view engines and call their `FindView` method. The view engine internally would translate requests for the views into `ViewEngineResult` objects. The ViewEngineResult objects return back the `View` if it exists or a list of the places it has searched for a suitable view.

If the view engine is Razor, the requests for views would be mapped into instances of compiled classes whose path is encoded into the class name. These classes are derived from `WebViewPage<T>` class and override the Execute method of the `WebViewPage` class. The HTML elements are handled by the `WriteLiteral` method inside the `Execute` method against the `Write` method for other elements. The `WriteLiteral` and `Write` methods pass the content to the `TextWrite`r object which is then passed to the IView.Render method. The MVC framework calls the `render` method and the output is written to the client through the `TextWriter` parameter of the `render` method.

Answer (score 0):

One one level, it becomes much easier to write a mock for this portion of the code.  Additionally, views can be whatever that implements IView, allowing for customized views, and potentially customized view engines.  It provides a greater level of flexibility for the developer using the framework, if it is needed.